# Getting width, height, positions along 3D space objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

I'm having some trouble grokking the relationship between an object's x and y position, and its 3D rotation and its z position.

How do you determine the object's height and width when it is manipulated in 3D space?  I assume it has to do with getRelativeMatrix3D() but don't see how.

If I want to determine the global x and y *along* an object (that is not the object's 'main' x or y, but at any point along the object's 'surface') how do I do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think getBounds has you covered for the width and height question.

```
  var obj:Sprite = new Sprite();
  obj.graphics.lineStyle(0,0,1);
  obj.graphics.beginFill(0xff9933,1);
  obj.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
  obj.graphics.endFill();

  obj.z = 0;
  addChild(obj);
  trace(obj.getBounds(obj));
  trace(obj.getBounds(this));

  obj.rotationX = 30;
  obj.rotationY = 50;
  trace(obj.getBounds(obj));
  trace(obj.getBounds(this));

  //output:
    (x=0, y=0, w=50, h=50)
    (x=0, y=0, w=50, h=50)
    (x=0, y=0, w=50, h=50)
    (x=0, y=-16, w=42, h=64)
```

I'm not sure about what you are asking for the 2nd part of your question though. Assuming you still want an answer...

> If I want to determine the global x and y along an object (that is not
>   the object's 'main' x or y, but at any point along the object's
>   'surface') how do I do that?